# Jelastic: any plan to create an official Terraform provider?

Tags: jelastic

[Jelastic API](https://docs.jelastic.com/api-overview) and [Jelastic CLI](https://docs.jelastic.com/cli) are awesome.

As a DevOps and SysAdmin I find vital nowadays to follow [Infrastructure as code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_code) practice and [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) is one of the most used tools for such purpose.

However I can't find any provider, neither among [official ones](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/index.html) nor among [community supported ones](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/type/community-index.html).

With API already in place and good looking, it should be straightforward to create the related Terraform provider.

Does Jelatic team have any plan to create it?

If you need help with it, but you like to keep the copyright, maybe Jelastic could create a *WIP* Github repository where community can start proposing Pull-Requests :)

Answer (score 1):

Topology-as-a-Code is already supported in Jelastic using JPS/CloudScripting.
Docs are [here](https://docs.cloudscripting.com). Many examples of how to describe different topologies in a code can be found [here](https://github.com/jelastic-jps).
Terraform is definitely a good tool, but its focus is mostly oriented to plain IaaS providers where containers / services orchestration abilities are limited.

Comment: If Jelastic orchestration is flexible it should be easy to respond to Terraform commands. People would like to use the same tool to declaratively instantiate their infrastructure. JPS feels like a non-standard custom thing. This is not just related to Terraform. Jelastic is a bit of a weird duck because they insist on such tools (such as JPS) to work with their infrastructure, and an unusual CLI design. Docker-compose support also took a while. Which is sad to see because I love Jelastic and would love Jelastic to be more programmatically approachable.

Comment: One thing to mention is Terraform focusses purely on infra creation, but JPS does much more than that - it provides for the entire lifecycle of that infra, such as event handlers for restarts or horizontal scale etc. (even code deploys).

Answer (score 1):

Jelastic supports the creation of a Kubernetes or Docker swarm cluster easily through its "Marketplace". So what you could try is using the Terraform Kubernetes adapter and point it at the Jelastic instance.

See:

- https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/guides/getting-started.html
- https://jelastic.com/blog/kubernetes-hosting-business-auto-clustering-pay-per-use/

However, I would love real platform support myself too.